# Add custom search under Support Case custom subtab

Tags: netsuite

1. I have created a saved search
2. I created a custom subtab under "support case" record type

Now I would like to show this saved search under the subtab. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom sublist to designate the location, name, and saved search. You can reference [Suite Answer id 48803](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48803) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. Creation of the subtab is all done and visible on forms required. I can add custom fields to the subtab, that works. The issue is how I can make the saved search visible on the custom subtab. I can't see how to do that.

Comment: My apologies for the oversight.  I've edited my response to directly answer your question of creating a sublist not a subtab.

Comment: Martha, thanks for your time. I found what I needed by this link. https://rsmus.com/what-we-do/services/technology/resources/netsuite-resource-center/netsuite-tips-tricks/how-to-add-a-saved-search-as-a-sublist-to-customer-form.html